# How to check whether the needed class has required method

Tags: java

For example consider the following code:

```
public class Stat<E> {
    // any data
    // lalala
    public void do_smt(E any_ob) {
        // if (any_ob has some method)
    }
}
```

In **public void do_smt(...)** i need to check if the object passed as an argument has some method
I thought interfaces may come in handy but i don`t know how to do it
Explain please in detail...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using an `interface`?

Comment: Try reading a tutorial. A simple google search would find you plenty. Like this one. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Hint: Every class that implements an interface, must implement all of the methods..

Comment: " i don`t know how to do it" what do you not know about using an `interface`.?

Comment: Is `E` supposed to represent only implementations of some interface with `methodYouWantToInvoke()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    void someMethod();
} 

public class Stat<E extends SomeInterface> {
    // any data
    // lalala
    public void do_smt(E any_ob) {
        // This is safe since you force E to implement SomeInterface
        any_ob.someMethod(); 
    }
}
```

Your object that you pass as a parameter is of type `E` but you also force it to be of type `SomeInterface` in the declaration `<E extends SomeInterface>`. Therefore, you can safely use it as the type `SomeInterface`.

Furthermore, if you implement the interface you are forced to implement its methods:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        // Must be implemented - otherwise you get compiler errors
    }
}
```

This [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) explains Java interfaces in a nice and simple way.